# How to join to previous client id in socket io after disconnection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have implemented socket io (version :0.10) for chat application. It works very smoothly except one issue.
Suppose two user are chating, now one of them lost the network. After getting network connectivity, how i can rejoin to that previously user that i was chatting with ?

Comment: Does your disconnected client establish connection to socket.io server successfully after getting network connectivity? If so, it should rejoin with the same socket.id, and therefore it should rejoin previous user automatically, I believe

Comment: Can you provide more information? What do you mean by "rejoin to previously user"?

Comment: No it does not connect to socket.io after getting network connectivity because i have used join function to connect two users. Socket io automatically handles rejoin with same socket id within 1 min only but after that it generate new socket id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

When two users first connected and joined, and new room is generated, you can send them the name of the room. And then pass that room name on the next connect

The code may look like following:

**server.js:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    if (socket.query.roomName) {
        var roomName = socket.query.roomName;
        //join to this room
    } else {
        //here you're generating a room name and join socket to this room
    }

    socket.emit('room_name', {roomName: roomName});
});
```

**client.js:**

```
socket.on('room_name', function(data) {
    socket.socket.options.query = 'roomName=' + data.roomName;
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

You can also try to pass `max reconnection attempts` and `reconnection limit` options when connecting to server:

```
var socket = io.connect('/', {
    'reconnection limit': 30000,  //max pause between reconnection attemps
    'max reconnection attempts': Infinity   //reconnect eternally
});
```

This worked with socket.io 0.9, not sure about 1.0